# Почему шрифты в разных браузерах отображаются по разному?

Tags: css

Почему то в Опере и Мозилле шрифты отображаются корректно, а в Хроме и Эксплорере нет. Шрифты некрасиво выглядят. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: У разных браузеров разный движок рендеринга. Это  и так понятно, что могут незначительно отличаться шрифты. Вопрос какой-то риторический.

А вот на счет "корректно" и "некрасиво" - предоставьте код html/css на котором проверяете и скриншоты "некрасивого" и "корректного" отображения. Тогда можно будет предметно поговорить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что браузеры по-разному их рендерят. Сглаживание, расстояние между буквами и т.д.

Comment: А как это исправить? Почему-то на этом сайте (хэшкод) шрифты отображаются нормально во всех браузерах.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, Вы пытаетесь использовать нестандартные шрифты, отсутствующие в этих браузерах. Если необходимость именно в этих шрифтах критична, используйте `JavaScript`-библиотеку куффон - она позволяет отрисовывать любые шрифты, не зависимо от их наличия у пользователя.

Comment: Нет. Шрифты стандартные. Используется arial. Но в Опере выглядит хорошо, а в Хроме каряво.